# check which link calls jquery popup

Tags: javascript, jquery, popup

how can i check which link is clicked to call a jQuery popup? Here, the data-card-id, which I have to pass to a JavaScript function, where a php Script is called with this value and then creates the content of the popup
My code which calls the popup:

```
<div class="cardbutton">
   <a href="#cardpopup" data-card-id="1" data-rel="popup" class="ui-btn" data-position-to="window">Anleitung starten</a>
</div>
<div class="cardbutton">
   <a href="#cardpopup" data-card-id="2" data-rel="popup" class="ui-btn" data-position-to="window">Anleitung starten</a>
</div>
```

The called Popup:

```
<div data-role="popup" id="cardpopup" data-dismissible="false" data-transition="slideup" class="cardpopup">
        <div data-role="header">
            <h1>cardpopupTemplate</h1>
        </div>
        <div data-role="main" class="ui-content" id="popupcardOuterDiv">
            <!-- hier folgt der generierte HTML Code für die einzelnen Schritte in der Anleitung -->
            <!-- here is the popupCode generated in JavaScript -->
        </div>
    </div>
```

myJavaScript:

```
$('#cardpopup').on({
                    popupbeforeposition: function(){
                        console.log($(this).data("card-id"));       // undefined :(
                        var h = $(document).height()-50;
                        var w = $(document).width()-50;
                        $("#cardpopup").css({
                                        "height": h,
                                        "width": w
                        });

                        createPopupManual(1, function(){           // here i have to pass the data-card-id value of the link               

                            var h = $("#popuppage1").height();
                            var w = $("#popuppage1").width();

                            $(".popupTopLeft").css({
                                        "height": h*0.8,
                                        "width": w*0.3
                            });
                            $(".popupTopRight").css({
                                        "height": h*0.8,
                                        "width": w*0.7,
                                        "left": (w*0.3)+16
                            });
                            $(".popupBottomLeft").css({
                                        "height": h*0.2,
                                        "width": w*0.3,
                                        "top": (h*0.8)+58
                            });
                            $(".popupBottomRight").css({
                                        "height": h*0.2,
                                        "width": w*0.7,
                                        "top": (h*0.8)+58,
                                        "left": (w*0.3)+16
                            });
                        });
                    },

                    popupafterclose: function(){
                        $('#cardpopup').slideDown();
                    }
                });
```

Comment: Is there a `click` handler bound to the `anchor` elements that trigger the `#cardpopup` events?

Comment: your comment here about $(this).data("card-id") being undefined, use this instead $(this).attr("data-card-id")

Comment: Hi. sorry for late answer, hab problems with inet for a few  days. I don't know if jQueri(ui)? adds an onclick handler to the `anchor` elements. i do not. but thats probably a workaround. I've tried `$(this).attr("data-card-id");` also. it's also undefined. the `$(this).data();` is a shortcut from jQuery.